# FirebaseMessagingService launch itself when Instrumentation test

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-instrumentation

When I try running Instrumentation test, the class extended FirebaseMessagingService launch itself so it crashes the test since the realm in there is not ready. I initialize the realm in my Application class.

Is there a way to stop the Firebase class launch itself when test?

The error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service .gcm. FirebaseMessagingService: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before creating a RealmConfiguration
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service android:name=".gcm.FirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The only place it's called is the Dagger2 injection in the extended class.

```
private val component: FcmServiceComponent by lazy {
    GetApplicationComponent.execute(this).fcmServiceComponent()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of **my custom application** open it in the code.

So check the stuff in the custom application first, then here.